# Mock a service in an acceptance test with Ember 2.7.0

Tags: ember.js, ember-testing

For older versions of ember, [this is the accepted answer for mocking a service in an acceptance test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28422375/how-to-mock-an-ember-cli-service-in-an-acceptance-test)

With Ember 2.7.0, I am not able to call startApp as per the answer above.
However, upon some quick tests, this appears to work just fine in injecting a service.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { module, test } from 'qunit';

let speakerMock = Ember.Service.extend({
  speak: function() {
    console.log("Acceptance Mock!");
  }
});

module('Acceptance | acceptance demo', {
  beforeEach: function() {
    // the key here is that the registered service:name IS NOT the same as the real service you're trying to mock
    // if you inject it as the same service:name, then the real one will take precedence and be loaded
    this.application.register('service:mockSpeaker', speakerMock);

    // this should look like your non-test injection, but with the service:name being that of the mock.
    // this will make speakerService use your mock
    this.application.inject('controller', 'speakerService', 'service:mockSpeaker');
  }
});

test('visit a route that will trigger usage of the mock service' , function(assert) {
  visit('/');

  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/');
  });
});
```

Am I missing something? I have doubts about:

a) Why this is not documented? Embers docs [provide excellent documentation on stubbing services in components](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/testing/testing-components/).

b) Is it because it is discouraged to mock services inside an acceptance test? Why?

Comment: @ykaragol 's answer is correct. It's a good idea in general to make acceptance testing with a black box technique. Could you clarify what do you want to achieve with it? Maybe we can find a more suitable way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

From [the guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/testing/):

> Acceptance tests are used to test user interaction and application
>   flow. The tests interact with the application in the same ways that a
>   user would, by doing things like filling out form fields and clicking
>   buttons. Acceptance tests ensure that the features within a project
>   are basically functional, and are valuable in ensuring the core
>   features of a project have not regressed, and that the project's goals
>   are being met.

It is not "clearly" mentioned but I understood that "acceptance tests behave the same with the real application". So you shouldn't mock something.

Comment: This is probably correct, but there are important cases where an acceptance test is desirable with some environment tweaks. For example, we use a service for a/b testing and we would like to lock that down to a particular experiment group for our test.